# Distance between two points in OpenCv based on known measurement

Tags: python, opencv, distance

I have an image in which, I have two set of coordinates between which I have draw a line.

```
#Get image
im_res = requests.get(image_url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(im_res.content))
img =  np.asarray(img)

#Draw first line
lineThickness = 3
cv.line(img, (ax, ay), (bx, by), (0,255,0), lineThickness)

#Draw second line
lineThickness = 3
cv.line(img, (cx, cy), (dx, dy), (0,255,0), lineThickness)

cv.imshow("Image", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Coordinates are A,B,C & D. I know the distance between C to D. However, the distance between A to B is unknown. What is the best way to calculate this in OpenCv?

[image: C-D distance is know. A-B is unknown.]

Is there an OpenCv specific function or method to do this? Especially the distance we are taking about is in pixels? I am sorry if this question is foolish, I really don't want to to end up getting wrong values due to lack of understanding in this topic.

I saw certain references to cv2.norm() and cv2.magnitude() as solution to this problem. However, I quite didnt't understand how to choose for my situation, keeping in mind in this case the distance is within an image/photo.

Comment: This is a simple math problem: `? = d(A,B) * 2.32 / d(C,D)`, where `d` is your distance function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming (it is a simple math problem)

Comment: @Berriel I have added more details to make it further clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You are basically asking which `d` should you use. Still, this is not a programming question. FYI, the euclidean norm (`cv2.NORM_L2`) is equal to the magnitude. This distance should provide you what you need. Have you tried using it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compute Euclidean from C to D and find the ratio of that with the known measurement.

`ratio = known / Euclidean`

Then find the Euclidean between A & B and use the earlier found ratio to convert the Euclidean to actual distance.

`distance = euclidean * ratio`

`euclidean "sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)"`

Comment: may i know the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue.